# Is there a VSCode action to close the sidebar if open, otherwise do nothing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's an action called `workbench.action.closePanel` that does exactly what you'd think it does; it closes the panel in VSCode if it's open, and if it's not open it does nothing. As far as I can tell, there is no equivalent for the sidebar in VSCode (`workbench.action.closeSidebar` doesn't work).

I don't want to use the `workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility` command; I want to have an explicit "close" command for the sidebar. Is there such a command and I'm just not seeing it? If it doesn't exist, I guess I'll open a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update in v1.43:

Adding a `workbench.action.closeSidebar` command.  Unbound by default.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/90404

---

I don't think there is a close-only command but you can make one with the `workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility` command.

```
 {
    "key": "alt+b",               // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "sideBarVisible"
  },
```

Now the `"toggle"` will only work if the sideBar is open and visible, otherwise it does nothing.  That's the usefulness of the `when` clauses.

You can use whatever keybinding you want (you can even make this work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> if you don't want it to toggle either).

---

BTW, the multi-command extension can take when clauses in the keybinding like:

```
{
  "key": "alt+b",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.closeSideBar&Panel" },
  "when": "sideBarVisible"
},
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a corresponding `panelVisible` or `panelIsOpen` clause for some reason.

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.closeSideBar&Panel",
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.closePanel",
      "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
    ]
  }
]
```

[And the extension author is investigating empowering `when` clauses in the settings, see https://github.com/ryuta46/vscode-multi-command/issues/3.]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think that works in the general case, but there's no native command, correct? I didn't mention it in the description, but I'm trying to use the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension to execute both "Close Panel" and "Close Sidebar" simultaneously. Not sure if I can get that extension set up to execute multiple shortcuts, since it only takes native commands as inputs...

Comment: Oh! I got it; I'll just use multiple commands with the same shortcut, but map them to different `when` clauses. Works like a charm. Thanks again! I might submit the feature request anyway because it'd be a nice to have command instead of playing with `when` clauses.

Comment: Glad you got it working, see some notes I added to the answer about multi-command: I use it alot.